# Facebook Like button can't upload images. Error processing file

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, upload, facebook-like

So this is the error message I see on product pages next to the like button.

> There were problems uploading
>   "http://www.palmercash.com/images/xxxxxxx.jpg" on behalf of your Open
>   Graph page. Here is the full error message our photo server reported:
>   "Error Processing File: Unable to process this photo. Please check
>   your photo's format and try again. We support these photo formats:
>   JPG, GIF, PNG, and TIFF."

The like button works fine, but the image doesn't show on facebook even though it is a correct URL.

I've done the linter and I just have a warning about og:url
but I've looked at other websites using the exact same code and the photos show fine.

Here is an example URL
http://www.palmercash.com/p-4440-mens-the-onion-mlk-t-shirt.aspx

I have checked the iis 6.0 logs and it appears facebook bots come and pull the images fine, as there is no error message there.  I'm just wondering what could cause this to happen.  I'm at a lose right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is because image you using as `og:image` is always returned by your server as `gzip` compressed without respecting `Accept-Encoding` HTTP header (even if `Accept-Encoding: identity` header passed with request your server still uses result in `Content-Encoding: gzip` and using compression).

Facebook's crawler probably doesn't pass this header and try to use this as image directly without decompressing it first.

Comment: Yes that was it. I turned of compression on the site and it works.  I'll see what I can do to get compression to work with facebook's crawler. Thanks so much for the help.